# Write a self replicating program that stops replicating after "printing" "Hello world!" with the filenames

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

Write a self replicating program, in the source code filename `H.*`, contianed in an empty folder then manually compile and run or just run the program if your chosen language is dynamic, and it should then just create a new source file, `e.*`, with the same exact source code, and automatically compile/run that new program, which makes the new source file `l.*`, etc. until the source file `!.*` is made, and that program should do essentially nothing once it is compiled/run. "Hello world!" has some repeated characters, so the second character should be created by a similar filename, just with a new `<space>` at the end. Programs that just make/compile source files from the single instance of the program are invalid, and yes, " " is a valid filename. It should appear to say "Hello World!" when viewed in the file explorer sorted by time created.

---

For example, if you were to attempt this challenge in python, than you would create the source file `H.py`, which complies and runs `e.py`, which then itself creates `l.py`, that file `l .py`, `o.py`, `.py`, `w.py`, `o .py`, `r.py`, `l  .py` and `d.py` which finally creates and runs `!.py`, which does not do anything once run.

Comment: "Self-replicating" implies that the program creates another file exactly identical to the original. Do the files all have to be identical, so that they have to read their own filename?

Comment: maybe re-write this as an ouroboros challenge? instead of the programs compiling the next one, just output the source, so H.py produces e.py... d.py produces H.py

Comment: @Doorknob yes, They would have to have the same content, and need to check their filename to see what to make the next one called.

Comment: Shouldn't the example end with `!.py`? Also, it states that `e.*` should create `e.*` again.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Fixed.

Comment: There are 3 `l`s in `Hello world!`. What should the filename of the 3rd be?

Comment: @user23013 add another space.

Comment: filenames are `H.*`,  `e.*`, `l.*`, `l .*`, `o.*`,  ` .*` ,  `w.*`, `o .*`, `r.*`, `l  .*`,  `d.*` and `!.*`

Comment: Will the directory initially be empty, apart from the code itself? If not, then will it have files with the same extension?

Comment: Added a condition, start with an empty folder containing only `H.py`

Comment: If we don't need an extension, can our files just be `H`, `e`, etc?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 194

```
import os,sys
h,A='H|e|l|l |o| |w|o |r|l  |d|!'.split('|'),sys.argv[0]
d,a,F=dict(zip(h,h[1:])),A.split('.')[0],file
if a in d:o=d[a]+'.py';F(o,'w').write(F(A).read());os.popen('python "'+o+'"')
```

Comment: the code runs without an error, but doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: oops, after re-reading the specs, it seems that I missed the fact that it had to run itself ... that's fixed

Comment: you have to name the script "H.py" by the way

Comment: It still seems to not be working, have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes I did !  I run under linux, so maybe running "python.exe" instead of "python" is the cause of the issue

Comment: Right now I am running from IDLE 2.7.8 on a Mac...

Comment: Managed to get it working with os.system('python H.py')

Comment: Confirmed after testing on a windows laptop, only runs when executed from the command line, or using os.system

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, <s>99</s> <s>88</s> 84

```
X=`grep -Po "(?<=#$0#)[^#]*" "$0"` #H#e#l#l #o# #W#o #r#l  #d#!
cp "$0" "$X"
sh "$X"
```

### Explanation:

1. First we create a regex from the name of the file (the argument `$0`).  For example, here is the regex constructed when the first file executes (`$0` is `H`):

   ```
    (?<=#H#)[^#]*
   ```

   This searches for a sequence of non-`#` characters preceded by `#H#`.  That is, it finds the next filename in a sequence of `#`-separated filenames.  (I used `#` so that the separator before `H` would function as the string delimiter itself, with the bonus of not needing a closing delimiter.)
2. Then we search (`grep`) the currently-executing file `"$0"` with this regex.  We need the `-P` flag (or similar) to use the lookbehind construct, and `-o` to only return the new filename, not the whole line.
3. We store the result (using backticks `` ` ``) of this whole evaluation in the variable `X`.
4. We copy (`cp`) the current file to the new file.
5. Finally we execute the new file with `sh`.

### Example usage:

```
robert@unity:~/hwbash$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 H
robert@unity:~/hwbash$ sh H
cp: cannot create regular file `': No such file or directory
sh: 0: Can't open
robert@unity:~/hwbash$ ls -lrt
total 48
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 H
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 e
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 l
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 l 
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 o
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52  
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 W
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 o 
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 r
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 l  
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 d
-rw-r--r-- 1 robert robert 97 May 25 23:52 !
robert@unity:~/hwbash$
```

### Updates

1. I saved some bytes by using `bash H` instead of `#!/bin/bash`.  This also means that I don't have to copy the executable permission, so sorting by timestamps works now (but you need to add a `sleep 1` or something to make it reliable).
2. Saved some more bytes by moving the string to a comment and changing the command from `bash` to `sh`.

Comment: I would appreciate any `bash` masters who could advise me on where I can trim off whitespace, if any...